# how to fetch data from mock Api in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a mock API having thousand of records. I have implemented infinite scroll. I want fetch 20 records from API and display only 10 of that.
I'm new to ionic 2 please suggest some simple code.
I'm using services. The same example which is given in angular tutorials

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

following is the code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {HeroService} from '../home/services/hero.service';
import {InMemoryDataService} from '../home/services/in-memory-data.service';
import {Hero} from '../home/services/hero'


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  heroes:Hero[];
  items=['Thor','Batman','Superman','Ironman','Spiderman']

  getHeroes()
  {
    this.heroservice.getHeroes().then(heroes=>this.heroes=heroes);
  }


i:number;
  constructor(public heroservice:HeroService) {


    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.items.push( this.items[i] );

    }
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');

    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        this.items.push( this.heroes[i].name );
      }
     console.log('Async operation has ended');
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
  }

}
```

Comment: just tell me how to fetch only 10 records and display it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/boosting-scroll-performance-in-ionic-2/) blog post by [Josh Morony](https://twitter.com/joshuamorony)